# Как правильно привязать обработчик, если элемент не был найден на странице?

Tags: javascript

Я использую такую конструкцию:

```
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);
```

Как правильно привязать обработчик, если элемент не был найден на странице?

```
$('#my_id').onclick = function() {

};
```

Чтобы не возникало ошибки:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of null (setting 'onclick')

Comment: `if ($('#my_id')) { ... }`, `$('...')?.onclick = ...`

Comment: $('#my_id')?.onclick = function() {

};
так можно попробовать, вставить оператор опциональной последовательности

Comment: @entithat @Александр-Родин `$('#my_id')?.onclick` вызывает ошибку **Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment**

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/optional-chaining
вот пример использования в чистом js, в jquery не силен
document.querySelector('#myID')?.addEventListener('click' , ()=>{}) - вот так вроде работает

Comment: Используйте лучше if

Comment: @АлександрРодин, с вызовами функции работает, а с оператором присваивания optional chaining нельзя использовать. По крайней мере пока.

Comment: @Grundy, я попутал с `??=`

Comment: @Александр-Родин `?.addEventListener` - подошло, спасибо. Если напишите ответом, то отмечу как решение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно реализовать с помощью [оператора опциональной последовательности](http://learn.javascript.ru/optional-chaining)

```
document.querySelector('#my_id')?.addEventListener('click' , ()=>{
   [код обработки]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Если `querySelector` возвращает null, вместо него можно подсунуть новый созданный элемент, на который будет добавлен обработчик.

```js
function $(selector) {
  return document.querySelector(selector) || document.createElement('div');
}


$('#test-1').addEventListener('click', () => console.log(0));
$('#test-2').addEventListener('click', () => console.log(0));
```

```html
<button id="test-1"> Click </button>
```

Но таким «молчаливым» подходом рискуете пропустить ошибку, если вдруг элемент должен был быть на странице, но его нет. Т.е. можно делать две функции, одну назвать `$`, пусть дает ошибку если элемента нет, вторую как-то по другому, чтобы использовать только там, где ожидается отсутствие элемента.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Что-то редко стал отвечать. Мне нравились всегда твои ответы.

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.$ = el => new Proxy({
  el: (el instanceof HTMLElement) ? el : document.querySelector(el), 
}, { 
   get(target, prop) {
     return target.el?.[prop]; 
   }, 
   set(target, prop, value) {
    if (target.el instanceof HTMLElement)           // присваивание по условию
      target.el[prop] = value; 
    return true; 
  }, 
});

$('#not-exist').onclick = () => console.log('');  // ошибки нет
$('#my-id').onclick = () => console.log('');
```

```html
<button id="my-id"></button>
```

Comment: Спасибо, это выглядит сложно. Постараюсь разобраться.